# SELECT FOR UPDATE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, bucle-for, update

Tengo un simple query que ejecuto en `mysql` con `phpmyadmin`:

`select * from tabla for udpate`;

Pero me da un error **"se esperaba una expresion"**. No logro darme cuenta que falta.  Gracias!

Comment: Seria ideal si muestras la estructura de la tabla y que datos deseas traer. complementa tu pregunta.

Comment: que necesitas hacer?

Comment: SELECT * FROM posiciones WHERE Id_torneo = 161 FOR UPDATE;

Comment: Error
Análisis estático:

Se encontraron 1 errores durante el análisis.

Palabra clave no reconocida. (near "FOR" at position 47)
consulta SQL: Documentación

SELECT * FROM posiciones WHERE Id_torneo = 161 FOR LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 1

Comment: bloquear ese registro para luego actualizarlo, puedo tener transacciones concurrentes que me generan problemas si no lo bloqueo.  Uso CodeIgniter y tengo manejo de transacciones, pero no tengo solucionada la concurrencia. Gracias!

Comment: *Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 1*  ...¿el error parece referirse a otra consulta, ya que en la consulta que compartes no veo que se use `LIMIT` por ningún lado. El mensaje de error hace referencia a una consulta escrita así: `SELECT * FROM posiciones WHERE Id_torneo = 161 FOR LIMIT 0, 25` la cual en efecto es errónea, debería ser: `SELECT * FROM posiciones WHERE Id_torneo = 161 FOR UPDATE LIMIT 0, 25`

Comment: Para añadir información a la pregunta, por favor edita la pregunta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Si usa FOR UPDATE con un motor de almacenamiento que usa bloqueos de página o fila, las filas examinadas por la consulta se bloquean contra escritura hasta el final de la transacción actual.

SELECCIONAR ... PARA ACTUALIZAR adquiere bloqueos de escritura en los objetos (filas, páginas, dependiendo del motor). Esto implica un poco de sobrecarga. Además, la base de datos (el motor InnoDB en la mayoría de los casos) necesita hacer una contabilidad adicional para el control de concurrencia de múltiples versiones (MVCC).

Consulte la documentación de [MySQL en select ... for update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) para obtener información detallada y ejemplos

Ademas estoy notando que tu query tienes errores de sintaxis :

```
   SELECT * FROM posiciones WHERE Id_torneo = 161 FOR LIMIT 0, 25
```

Debiera ser:

```
  SELECT * FROM posiciones WHERE Id_torneo = 161 FOR UPDATE
```

**SOLUCION**
Debes quitar en la configuración de tu motor el LIMIT , es por eso que tienes el problema al momento de ejecutar tu query.

Comment: Si la consulte pero no encontré la solución, de hecho me pone el mismo ejemplo.

Comment: que motor usas exactamente?

Comment: uso mysql 5.7.14

Comment: Según lo que mencionas abajo, tienes errores de sintaxis, en mi respuesta te escribí la forma correcta

Comment: SELECT * FROM posiciones WHERE Id_torneo = 161 FOR UPDATE
.....lo tengo asi y me tira el error que adjunté...incluso con punto y coma al final

Comment: es como que de alguna manera el motor interpreta "FOR UPDATE" como FOR LIMIT

Comment: si, pero tu motor debe tener el `limit 0, 25` por defecto, es por eso que te esta indicando en el error!!! que motor estas usando para correr el query? mysql? o en phpmyadmin? fijate en el `Limit` debe estar setiado por defecto!!!

Comment: ahora lo estoy corriendo desde phpmyadmin, voy a revisar lo del limit.  La tabla tiene solo 5 registros con esa condicion.

Comment: PHPMYADMIN por defecto te le aplica limit a tu consulta es eso lo que esta causando el problema, si corres a través de otro soft te correrá sin problemas.

Comment: Desde el Soft....

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update posiciones set PTS = PTS + 3,PG = PG + 1,GF = GF + 3,PJ = PJ + 1, GC = GC' at line 1

SELECT * FROM posiciones WHERE Id_torneo = 161 FOR UPDATE; update posiciones set PTS = PTS + 3,PG = PG + 1,GF = GF + 3,PJ = PJ + 1, GC = GC +0 where Id_torneo = 161 and Id_equipo =7;

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/torneos/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: si no logro resolverlo con FOR UPDATE lo hare de otra manera....

Comment: Bajate el dbforge for MySQL express, y corres el query sin el limit, verás que tu problema se solucionará.